# What can I use to rejoin porcelain broken pieces?

Tags: home, adhesive

**Background:**

I have in my room a porcelain statue given to me by my mother.

This morning, I forgot the statue's location and it fell to the ground. Fortunately, it didn't break completely, but its neck was separated from its body.

The broken surfaces are smooth/clear enough to just use some kind of glue and join them.

I don't have a "super glue" or anything like that at hand right now, but I'm curious if I can use another substance to join these porcelain pieces.

So, as the title says:

**What can I use to rejoin porcelain broken pieces?**

Comment: You ask for an answer that's not super glue, so here's a comment - If it is porcelain that is not porous, super glue is the best glue for the job that I'm aware of, however, if it is ceramic and absorbs moisture, it will tend to just absorb the glue and not provide a strong bond.

Comment: @JPhi1618, Oxinabox I understand; may you please elaborate your comments as answers instead?

Comment: Sodium silicate, aka *waterglass*, is a traditional repair cement for ceramics. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_silicate#Pottery

Comment: It seems my comment was deleted. Possibly for being too close to an answer  (though In which case I would have rather a convert to answer, or for someone else to post it as an answer).
But my point was. This question can not be answered.
As the requirement is " "super glue" or sort like that". And my comment (and what I beleive to be the truth), is that there is nothing that is not like superglue that can glue pottery (eg waterglass, as mentioned in the comment by DrMoishe).

The question might as well be: "I need a to make a website, but I don't have a computer or anything like that"

Comment: @Oxinabox, well, I really don't know what I say, I will leave that moderators decides if this question is off-topic for any reason: I don't want enter to discussion but, I read the Tour and (for what I understand), my question is on-topic "maybe it's hard, but on-topic nonetheless", but, **if my question is deleted, I wont _fight or reply_ for it.**

Comment: The easy change is just to remove the glue restriction. Then Zeiss Ikon's answer becomes correct.

Comment: I have mended ceramics a few times with special ceramic glue. I use a German brand so I won't name it here, I got it from the DIY shop. Anyway, the results are not very satisfactory. If it's a handle it will fall off again sooner or later, and although it says it's dishwasher safe it isn't. The answers here recommend super glue so that's what I'll use next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An experienced hand with slow-setting two-part epoxy (sometimes called araldite) is probably perferred over cyanoacrylate, but the water-thin super glue would be the best second choice.

For epoxy, you'd ensure the glue is mixed thoroughly, apply a thin coat to one surface, join the parts and clamp them in place, ignoring glue that squeezes out of the joint (it'll be easy to remove from the glossy glazed surface after it cures).  Don't disturb the joint until the full curing time has passed, and keep it in a warm room (above 20 C).  Once fully cured, the excess glue can be easily chipped off the glossy surface and carefully trimmed even with the glaze with a razor blade or similar thin, sharp blade.

For thin super glue, you'd join the parts dry, apply a minimum drop of glue at the join, and let it draw into the joint.  If the joint area is large, you may need a second drop.  Curing may take minutes, rather than seconds, on a non-porous material, but can be accelerated by breathing your moist, warm breath on the joint.  Be careful not to use too much; it's difficult to remove cleanly, even from glossy surfaces, and there's a hazard of gluing your fingers to the statue.

The down side of this is that either glue will preclude a second try with the other, so it may be sensible to intentionally break a cheap item of the same material, to gain practice gluing.

Answer (score 2):

My wife is an ardent crafter and uses many kinds of adhesives in various projects.  Her recommendation was a two-part epoxy.

I checked around the web after she gave her answer, and found a [cermaic repair site](http://www.lakesidepottery.com/Pages/Pottery-tips/epoxies-vs-cyanoacrylate-super-glue-crazy-glue-ceramic-china-repair.htm), which said:

> Many people ask us for advice and one of the most common questions is "Can I use Super or Crazy Glues to fix my broken ceramic? It’s so much easier than 2-part epoxies!" There is a misunderstanding about the difference between super glues and epoxy and they are therefore sometimes used interchangeably but, super glues and epoxy glue are different and have specific purposes.

The article is a bit lengthy, but it concludes:

> [We do] not use super glues for ceramic repair and restoration – super glues are just not strong and durable enough. In most of our ceramic restoration ... we use high-end non-yellowing 5 minute clear epoxies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gold, silver, or other metals that will actually highlight the break.

[image: can't show image, google "gold mend dish"]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, silver and other materials can be used.  [enter link description here](http://lakesidepottery.com/Pages/kintsugi-repairing-ceramic-with-gold-and-lacquer-better-than-new.htm)[image]

Comment: Please add details of how to do it

Comment: That answer has already been given.